# Issue with integrating Google button

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I try to follow the instruction provided on this page: https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/button

I have created a page with a code copied from the example on the page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Integrate with Google button demo: custom tag</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <g:additnow applicationid="goffboofghicjemnbcoapndfegjpdmme"></g:additnow>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, when I try to run the page I receive 400 Bad Request. The error message comes from running the following link inside Google's JS:

https://apis.google.com/additnow/additnow.html?usegapi=1&applicationid=goffboofghicjemnbcoapndfegjpdmme&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cloudrein.com&gsrc=3p&ic=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.Y7yo-hE6f2w.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Ft%3Dzcms%2Frs%3DAItRSTOCCewNInyW1jNvLdupkCgdxhOtiQ

Link to page: https://www.cloudrein.com/gapps.html

Please help.

Thank you,
Evgeny

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, I used Chrome Web Store Item ID instead of using App Id from Google Apps Marketplace. :)